# What hashing algorithm does Windows 10 use to store passwords?

Tags: windows, algorithm, hash, passwords, windows-10

I have recently been taught about hashing in A-Level Computing and wondered if I could write a program to hash passwords using the same algorithm as Windows 10.

The reason I want to use the same algorithm as used to store passwords in Windows 10 is because I would like to compare the hashed value I generate to the value stored by Windows.

What hashing algorithm does Windows 10 use to store passwords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The NT hash is simply a hash. The password is hashed by using the MD4 algorithm and stored.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994558(v=ws.10).aspx

> NTLM [..] uses RC4 for encryption. Deriving a key from a password is as specified in [RFC1320](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1320.txt) and [FIPS46-2].

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236715.aspx

This appears to [still be the case in Windows 10](https://adsecurity.org/?p=1535), although it's now stored completely differently (in an isolated virtual machine for protecting passwords).

[This reasoning](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30657/1427) also backs up the idea that the hash algorithm won't have changed, but it's not a certainty.

NB. that this applies to a standalone computer. If the computer is joined to an Active Directory domain, the domain controllers use an AES based system for password hashing.